# Exoplayer not playing local mov file

Tags: android, exoplayer, mov, media-source

I am unable to run .mov files from URLs or local mp4 files using exoplayer. When I am trying to run .mov file from a local path it throws an `UnrecognizedInputFormatException` exception (stack trace below). Does Exoplayer support running mov files from the local path in any way?

```
com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.UnrecognizedInputFormatException: None of the available extractors (MatroskaExtractor, FragmentedMp4Extractor, Mp4Extractor, Mp3Extractor, AdtsExtractor, Ac3Extractor, TsExtractor, FlvExtractor, OggExtractor, PsExtractor, WavExtractor) could read the stream.
                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractorHolder.selectExtractor(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:820)
                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.source.ExtractorMediaPeriod$ExtractingLoadable.load(ExtractorMediaPeriod.java:742)
                                                        at com.google.android.exoplayer2.upstream.Loader$LoadTask.run(Loader.java:315)
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                                                        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                                                        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

This is how I am building media-source :

```
    private MediaSource buildMediaSource(Uri uri) {
    DataSource.Factory dataSourceFactory = new FileDataSourceFactory();
    return new ExtractorMediaSource.Factory(
            new FileDataSourceFactory()).
            createMediaSource(uri);

}
```

TIA

Comment: Looks like it doesn't support mov files at all. Are you 101% sure that it worked with network file?

Comment: yes i am sure . 
Here is a sample url : http://techslides.com/demos/samples/sample.mov
its working using exoplayer.